# How to use receipt of xmpp message in iOS?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I get the following in the console using the XEP-0184 but I don't klnow how to use it.

What I want to do, is **to mark the message as sent or received.**

```
 SEND: <message id="984C1EEA-5B19-4324-9825-8DFB71597ED7" type="chat" to="test"><body>asdasdasdasd</body><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/></message>


 RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="test1/15326383401393246504731715"      to="test2/3257646811393246483819548"><received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="984C1EEA-5B19-4324-9825-8DFB71597ED7"/></message>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: hi Chris, did you find a way to use the reciept, even i need mark the message as sent or received. I tried to use id but `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject` does not have the id attribute.

Comment: If anyone need help like in this problem please leave a comment.

Comment: did you find the solution for that

Answer (score 0):

It means the message was received by by the recipient/the client you sent the message. You can either update the UI of your app(to mark it as received - WhatsApp usually does two ticks to indicate that a message was delivered). or message status if you are storing it in some database.

Please have a look at http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html

Comment: Hey there
I know what those mean. What I dont know is how to use them in order to mark the message as sent/received.